# Searching in Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have sorted ascending number if you do abs(arr) in below code, I am trying to search for index where sign got changed from negative to positive. Wrote this below code, but for some reasons, I believe we can improve it or optimize more. Any tips and tricks ?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([-1,-2,-3, 4, 5, 6])
_cut_index_1 = np.where(arr > 0)[0][0]
_cut_index_2 = np.where(arr < 0)[0][-1]
arr[_cut_index_1] # output:   4
arr[_cut_index_2] # output:  -3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current solution does two passes over the input array (the two invocations of `np.where`) which as stated seems wasteful. One simple way to solve the problem is to use `np.argmax` which will take linear time:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([-1, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6])
np.argmax(arr > 0) # Return (index) 3
```

At this point, if we can assume (as you seem to imply) that there is a single position of interest (and/or that we only care about the first one, read from left to right) we are done: just decrement one from the answer and you have the other cut-off point (but do check whether we are at a corner case so as not to return a non-valid index).

But in fact, if you can safely assume that the input is sorted, you can avoid doing a linear scan and not even read the whole input. For this, you can do a binary search via [searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). Theoretically, this is faster (i.e., logarithmic vs. linear in the worst case) but in practice this will depend on the size of the array. That is, for small enough arrays a linear scan will be faster due to cache locality (or, at least, that should be the case modulo your hardware details).